# CUDA+OpenCV：this application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) 

Tags: opencv, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

When i ran the program in vs2008 on windows7 x64,using cuda4.1 and opencv2.3.it        occurs"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)....",there are no compile and link bugs,it occurs only in the runtime,it has drive me crazy.any help will be appreciate! thanks!
Here is my code:

```
#include <cutil_math.h>
#include <cutil_inline.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <book.h>
#include <cpu_bitmap.h>

#define ThreadX  16
#define ThreadY  16  

texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> texRefSource;
texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> texRefTarget;

__constant__ float c_trans[9];

__global__ void transformKernel(float* dev_bitmap,int width, int height)
{
    //计算拾取坐标
    unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    float3 v=make_float3(x,y,1);
    float3 r0=make_float3(c_trans[0],c_trans[1],c_trans[2]);
        float3 r1=make_float3(c_trans[3],c_trans[4],c_trans[5]);
        float3 r2=make_float3(c_trans[6],c_trans[7],c_trans[8]);

    float tz=dot(r2,v);
        float tx=dot(r0,v)/tz;
    float ty=dot(r1,v)/tz;
    dev_bitmap[y * width + x] = tex2D(texRefTarget, tx, ty);
}

int main()
{  
    // load and set source file
    IplImage* source=cvLoadImage("C:\\1368.bmp"); 
    IplImage* sourcegray =cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(source),source->depth,1);
    cvCvtColor(source,sourcegray,CV_BGR2GRAY);//image1图像灰度化

    int w1 = sourcegray->width;
    int h1 = sourcegray->height;
    int size1=w1*h1;

    cudaArray* SourcecuArray;
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc1 = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0,                 0,cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
    cudaMallocArray(&SourcecuArray, &channelDesc1, w1, h1);
    cudaMemcpyToArray(SourcecuArray, 0, 0, sourcegray->imageData,size1,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    texRefSource.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap; //循环寻址方式
    texRefSource.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    texRefSource.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;

    cudaBindTextureToArray(texRefSource, SourcecuArray, channelDesc1);

    // load and set target file
    IplImage* target=cvLoadImage("C:\\1369.bmp");
    IplImage* targetgray =cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(target),target->depth,1);
    cvCvtColor(target,targetgray,CV_BGR2GRAY);//image1图像灰度化
    cvNamedWindow("before", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("before", targetgray);

    int w2 = targetgray->width;
    int h2 = targetgray->height;
    int size2=w2*h2;

    cudaArray* TargetcuArray;
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc2 = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0,cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
    cudaMallocArray(&TargetcuArray, &channelDesc2, w2, h2);
    cudaMemcpyToArray(TargetcuArray, 0, 0, targetgray->imageData,size2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    texRefTarget.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap; //循环寻址方式
    texRefTarget.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    texRefTarget.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;

    cudaBindTextureToArray(texRefTarget, TargetcuArray, channelDesc2);

    //----------------------构造从image1----->image2的变换矩阵，存入常量内存c_trans----------//
     float u[9]={-0.00363945, 123.461, 123.154, 1.0105, 0.868716, 1.2, 1.2, -0.000110196, 0.000174003};
     float matM[3][3]={ u[3]*cos(u[0]), u[4]*sin(u[0]),  0,
                    -u[5]*sin(u[0]),  u[6]*cos(u[0]), 0,
                    u[7],             u[8],             1}; 
     CvMat M = cvMat(3,3,CV_32FC1,matM);  //求得的是image2-->image1的M。
     CvMat invM = cvMat(3,3,CV_32FC1,matM);  //求得的是image1-->image2的M。
     cvInvert(&M,&invM);
     for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
         for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
         {
             c_trans[i*3+j]=CV_MAT_ELEM(invM,float,i,j); 
         }
     }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

     float *dev_bitmap=NULL;
     int size=size1*sizeof(float);
     cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_bitmap, size);

    //开始变换图像
     dim3 blockSize(ThreadX, ThreadY); 
     dim3 gridSize( (w1+ThreadX-1) / blockSize.x, (h1+ThreadY-1) / blockSize.y);
     transformKernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(dev_bitmap,w1,h1);

     CPUBitmap bitmap(w1,h1);
     cudaMemcpy(bitmap.get_ptr(),(unsigned char*)dev_bitmap,bitmap.image_size(),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

     bitmap.display_and_exit();

     cvWaitKey(0);

     cvReleaseImage(&source);
     cvReleaseImage(&sourcegray);
     cvReleaseImage(&target);
     cvReleaseImage(&targetgray);


     cvDestroyAllWindows();

     cudaFreeArray(SourcecuArray);
     cudaFreeArray(TargetcuArray);
     cudaFree(dev_bitmap);
     return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: That error code is INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, and usually means you are trying to mix 64 bit and 32 bit libraries in a 32 bit application.

Comment: Then how can I solve this problem?thanks a lot~

Comment: I am not a regular visual studio user so I can give you a detailed answer, but check you build rules. It is likely you are mixing 64 and 32 bit code somewhere.